# Como voltar em um ponto especifico do codigo em c++?

Tags: c++, return

Eu preciso voltar no código em três determinado ponto específicos e não sei como fazer. Preciso em momentos diferentes do meu código eu preciso retornar a um dos três pontos já estabelecidos, mas são pontos que não são no inicio do código, então não sei como fazer porque preciso que ele volte e rode todo o resto do código normalmente. Por exemplo, estou rodando a linha 500 do código e, dependendo da interação do usuário, preciso retornar a linha 250, na linha 700 ele pergunta novamente se quero voltar a 250, e de novo na linha 1100 Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou modularizar o seu código? Talvez seja o que precisa, pelo que entendi você possui um `main` com mais de 1200 linhas é isso?

Comment: Sim, eu possuo um main com mais de 1200 linhas, e nesse ponto em que eu preciso que ele volte, preciso que ele passe novamente por todo o código após a linha 250, por exemplo

Comment: Poste algo compilável, mesmo que não seja o programa todo

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser voltar em código, normalmente acaba-se em pensar no `goto`, porém o uso do goto para qualquer programa maior que um teste de funcionalidade não é recomendado ou até mesmo constantemente ódiado, pois o goto quebra a linearidade que um programa deve ter quando é lido por um humano, gerando o [Código espaguete](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_espaguete) que deixa tudo mais complicado de entender, fazer manutenção e adaptar para uso em mais lugares, basicamente, é uma má pratica não só da programação, como para você e todo que forem ler seu código, o que você precisa não é de GOTO, afinal, não esta programando em assembly, o que você precisa é simplesmente de [funções](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm), se possível o mais modulares possível.

Uma maneira muito simples de exemplificar isso é imaginando o código a seguir onde você precisa pedir um numero:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

main(){
    
    pontoInicial:
    
    int i;
    printf("\nDigite um numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &i);
    printf("%i\n", i);
    system("pause");
     
    //Muito código depois e você precisa voltar para pedir o número novamente
    //e rodar o código a partir dele apenas se usaria com o checkpoint feito anteriormente
    goto pontoInicial;
}
```

Porém isso é um código bem porco e é facil de imaginar que isso não dá certo a longo prazo, muito menos para programas grandes, então é facil criar uma função para fazer isso e retornar o que quiser (ou void sem return se não for necessário) assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int retornaNumero(){
    int temp;
    printf("\nDigite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    printf("%d\n", temp);
    system("pause");
    return temp;
}

main(){
        
    int i = retornaNumero();
    //Assim as coisas ficaram muito mais simples e você pode usar quaaantas vezes quiser e o
    //código continua seguindo seu fluxograma de maneira correta e tudo fica mais limpo e modular
}
```

[Funções](http://linguagemc.com.br/funcoes-em-c/#:%7E:text=Uma%20fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20nada%20mais%20%C3%A9,do%20nome%20atribu%C3%ADdo%20a%20ela.) úteis e [modularização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularidade#Ferramentas_para_a_modulariza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) do código são muito importantes para manutenção e facilidade de leitura, recomendo muito tentar fazer isso com seu código, e cuidado em forçar recursões